# Mock Static Methods in JUnit5 using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit5, powermockito, junit5-extension-model

Need help for Mocking Static methods using JUnit5 with PowerMockito framework.

[Powermock junit5 and mockito2.x not working RunnerTestSuiteChunker not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995276/powermock-junit5-and-mockito2-x-not-working-runnertestsuitechunker-not-found)

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


@PrepareForTest(EnvironmentUtils.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class RuleControllerTest {       

        @Before
        public void setup() {           
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(EnvironmentUtils.class);
        }   


        @Test
        public void test_rule_create_rule() throws IOException {
            when(EnvironmentUtils.isCF()).thenReturn(true);

        }
}
```

and pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I followed Junit5 sample from here,
1) https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5
2) [Junit5 mock a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830441/junit5-mock-a-static-method)

But facing an issue as, I know there is an existing [issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/929) for Junit5 with powermock but any one knows any other way to Mock static methods using JUnit5 using powermock.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: @Progman i see a clear question here, along w/ how he tried to resolve. I disagree with your comment :(

Answer (score 23):

With mockito v 3.4.0 we can simply use **mockStatic()** method without powermock library :

```
 try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
   mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
   assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
   mocked.verify(Foo::method);
 }

assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
```

Latest documentation and example :
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.10/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Comment: but with that you can mock only one method in context, right?

Answer (score 2):

As your link suggests, still you can't do power mock stuff with junit-5 directly, simply because there's ***no*** `PowerMockRunner` (Extension) still available for junit-5.

However, In your above code possibly what has gone wrong is this line.

```
when(EnvironmentUtils.isCF()).thenReturn(true);
```

Here, note that you are using `when` of `mockito` (by `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`)

Instead, you have to use the one of `PowerMockito`. So

Remove this line `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`

Instead, add this. `import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;`

Answer (score 2):

You're using `@Before` which is a JUnit4 annotation. JUnit5 in turn has `@BeforeEach` / `@BeforeAll` (whichever suits your requirement). Also, your import for `@Test` is from JUnit4 but not from JUnit5 which should be `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` ;)

Comment: Tests are run with `junit-vintage-engine`. This doesn't address PowerMock or the static method question