# Unit Test for different conditions in the same method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am wondering if I should test the same parts of a method when there are multiple conditions in this method in Unit Testing. I mean that, for example, in the following method there are 2 conditions (the code is simplified and unnecessary parts are omitted):

```
private Boolean demo() {
    
        Boolean result = null;
        List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll();
        
        if (/* condition 1 */) {            
                result = true;
        } else { /* condition 2 */                       
                result = false;
        }
        
        employeeRepository.saveSalary(BigDecimal salary);
        employeeRepository.saveEmployee(Employee employee);
        
        return result;
}
```

When I test condition 1, I also test the parts in the `saveSalary()` and `saveEmployee()` methods.

In this scene, when I test condition 2 using another test method in the same Unit Test class, should I also test `saveSalary()` and `saveEmployee()` methods again? Or just verifying them as `verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).saveSalary(any());` and `verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).saveEmployee(any());` enough? What is the correct approach for this kind of situation?

Comment: employeeRepository should be a mock in your test. Then user mockito.when to have two test for testing condition 1 and another to test condition 2. Otherwise you are performing integration tests and depending on the implementation (and correctness) of employeeRepository.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I completely asked another part. of course I use mockito.when to have two test for testing condition 1 and another to test condition 2. But what about the last part after if block? Should I also test these 2 lines for both of the tests that are created for condition testing?

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand your question entirely previously. For me, if it something that you want to verify (it is part of your logic), then you should call verify. You should test each different "branch" entirely. If someone refactors your code, then it will always have the guarantee that her changes will work the same way as intended. If you do so only when testing condition 1 for example, then a refactor can break the method purpose (this is specially true on public methods).

Comment: Suppose that I write 2 test method e.g. `test_Condition_One()` and `test_Condition_Two()`. In `test_Condition_One()` method, I will also test `employeeRepository.saveSalary()` and `employeeRepository.saveEmployee()` lines. In this situation, is there any need to test these 2 lines in `test_ConditionTwo()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Your question reveals the answer...

When writing UnitTest with each test method we document **a single expectation** about the behavior of the *Code Under Test* (cut).

From your question I understand that you expect the *cut* to  call the methods on `employeeRepository` regardless of the value returned. Therefor I'd  have thee test methods, one with each condition plus one that does not meet either condition, which verify  that the methods on `employeeRepository` are called at all (regardless of the parameter values).
In addition Id have a fourth test method that verifies, that the methods on  `employeeRepository` are called with the expected parameters (since they don't seam to depend on the conditions) and maybe in the right order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations. Actually my question is something like that (I need to clarify a little bit more): Assume that there are 2 conditions + 1 CRUD operation in my service method that I test. In this scene, I write Unit Test 1 for Condition 1, then write Unit Test 2 for Condition 2. >>>

Comment: **1.** In this scene, should I write a separate test for the CRUD operation (let's say Save) as the third Unit Test?

Comment: **2.** SHould I test this Save operation in all of the 2 Unit Tests that is written for 2 conditions?

Comment: Following the Single Responsibility Pattern (SRP) the actual CRUD operation should live in a class of its own having its own set of UnitTests. In the test verifying the actual  cut  I'd only test that the "CRUD service" (which is a dependency to the actual cut) is called at all with the right parameters.