# How to use PowerMock in JUnit5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, powermock

As mentioned on some articles like [Simplifying Junit, Mockito And PowerMock](https://aggarwal-rohan17.medium.com/simplifying-junit-mockito-and-powermock-d1392059ce87), I cannot use PowerMock in JUnit5.

As I cannot downgrade my JUnit version to 4 and need to stick with JUnit5, how can I use PowerMock in JUnit5 to test static methods? Or if it is not possible, what should I use? I tried MockStatic, but I am not sure if it is a proper way to test static method. What would you suggest?

Comment: It looks like you can use mockito v3.4.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920995/1479895

Comment: Thanks, ı will look at. Is there any annotation for the test class except from default one `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` ?

Comment: @AntonBelev The second question is that: Should I call my service method that I am testing inside `try` block?

Comment: In any case I get "there were zero interactions with this mock" error. Any idea?